# Rails/Ruby: Self-referential association using dependent: :destroy causing duplicate callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback, associations

It was difficult to properly word my issue in the title, but I'll try to briefly explain it in a bit more detail.

I have need to use a self-referencing association in one of my models, like so:

```rb
class StandingEvent < Event
  has_many :children, class_name: "StandingEvent", foreign_key: "parent_id", dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: "StandingEvent"

  after_destroy :do_stuff

  ...
end
```

The issue is, when I call the `StandingEvent.destroy` method on a series of `StandingEvent` records -- such as from another associated model for example -- *any `StandingEvent` record that has an assigned `parent_id` invariably runs the `after_destroy` callback method **twice***.

This is a problem when I want to destroy all `StandingEvent` records in a collection, such as this method called elsewhere in the code:

```rb
def destroy_standing_events
  self.standing_events.each do |standing_event|
    standing_event.destroy
  end
end
```

I have of course gathered that this is expected behavior from using `dependent: :destroy` for the `has_many :children` association, since it is clearly calling the `destroy` for the child first if one exists, *then* calling `destroy` for the original parent.  This is a problem, however, in the above `destroy_standing_events` example because even after the `destroy` method has been called on a child record via the `dependent: :destroy` clause, it will make the `destroy` call a second time, triggering my `after_destroy :do_stuff` callback a second time.

**Attempted Solutions**

Thus far I've tried the following (without success):

- Changed `after_destroy` to `before_destroy` just in case the callback order was funky
- Tried checking `standing_event.destroyed?` status in both the outside `destroy_standing_events` method and the inner `:do_stuff` callback method
- Attempted to use a custom flag attached to the `StandingEvent` model to indicate whether the actions of `:do_stuff` had already been applied or not to "hack" a way to prevent duplication.

Unfortunately, so far the only "solution" I've found is essentially running a secondary database lookup in the outside `destroy_standing_events` method to ensure the record hasn't already been destroyed prior to finalizing the `destroy` call, as seen below:

```rb
def destroy_standing_events
  self.standing_events.each do |standing_event|
    # Verify that each event exists
    standing_event = StandingEvent.find_by(id: standing_event.id)
    standing_event.destroy unless standing_event.nil?
  end
end
```

So, while the above solution technically works, *I can't help but feel like there's a better solution out there, especially one that doesn't require so many extra database queries.*

Any guidance or help would be much appreciated!

### SOLUTION

Thanks to @pdobb's suggestion below, I was able to figure out a resolution to my specific issue using only one database query by limiting the collection of returned `StandingEvents` to *only those records without any parent/children associated records, **OR** records that were parents*.

```rb
StandingEvent < Event
  has_many :children, class_name: "StandingEvent", foreign_key: "parent_id", dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: "StandingEvent"

  def self.dominant
    where.any_of(no_parent.merge(no_children), has_children)
  end
  def self.has_children
    includes(:children).where.not(children_events: { id: nil })
  end
  def self.no_children
    includes(:children).where(children_events: { id: nil })
  end
  def self.no_parent
    where(parent: nil)
  end
```

Above is the relevant code for the `StandingEvent` model, where I added four class methods to query specific collections.  I then grab the merge of both the `no_parent` and `no_children` collection which represents all the records without associations that can freely be destroyed.  Then, because of the `has_many :children, dependent: :destroy` clause in `StandingEvent`, I also need to include those records that have `children` using the `has_children` method.

To simplify the call, all the above is combined into the `dominant` method, where I'm using the [ActiverecordAnyOf gem](https://github.com/oelmekki/activerecord_any_of) just to simply create an easy "OR" database query (though the same result without the *AnyOf* gem could be accomplished with custom SQL or AREL.)

The end result, as suggested by @pdobb, is that I can call the `dominant` records to be `destroyed` in my outside call:

```rb
def destroy_standing_events
  self.standing_events.dominant.destroy_all
end
```

Comment: Is it required to call the after_destroy callback in the context of this `destroy_standing_events` method? If not, using `standing_events.clear` may work.

Comment: @pdobb Yes, I'm afraid using the callback is required in this case.  The `after_destroy` allows the `StandingEvent` model to perform some necessary cleanup actions.  Unfortunately, running those cleanup actions twice for a single model is problematic (hence the issue overall).  I could technically run that `after_destroy` callback code manually from within the `destroy_standing_events` call, but that seems very messy for sure and I'd much rather take advantage of the nature of closed systems as much as possible by keeping that stuff within the inherent model actions itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about only attempting to delete parents in the first place (excluding children)?

```
def destroy_standing_events
  standing_events.is_parent.destroy_all
end
```

Where `is_child` is a scope defined on *StandingEvent*:

```
class StandingEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :is_parent, -> { where.not(parent_id: nil) }
end
```

Then your loop would not include children to begin with and the `dependent: :destroy` option would take care of destroying associated children. Note: the scope syntax assumes Rails 4.x.

Comment: A solid suggestion, but unfortunately it doesn't cover all scenarios.  The `.children/.parent` relationship is optional and in fact more often than not, a `StandingEvent` record is simply it's own entity.

That said, I don't know what the standard procedure is here, but I'm marking your reply as the answer because it did lead me down the right path/line of thinking to come up with the solution.  You can see the details in my edited original post, but the gist is that I created a few scopes as you suggest that only find either solo records OR records with children, then delete them all.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks! And thanks for showing your solution. I like that ActiveRecordAnyOf gem idea :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is a cycle free graph you could do something like the following
to get rid of the dependent destroys

```
def self.dest_rec node
  node.children.each{ |c| dest_rec c }
  node.destroy
end
```

If the graph is not cycle free adapt to

```
 def self.dest_rec node, already_destroyed={}
   node.children.each do | c |
      next if already_destroyed[c.id]
      already_destroyed[c.id] = true # What a liar I am ;)
      dest_rec c, already_detroyed
   end
   node.destroy
 end
```

this is a general case with n db lookups for a tree height (or longest noncyclic path)
of n.

Can we do better?